# Correctly typing a chain of functions

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

Say I have a type:

```js
type Module<TInput, TOutput> = {
  passThrough: (input: TInput) => TOutput;
}
```

representing a swappable "module" with a function that takes in a value (of type `TInput`) and outputs another (of type `TOutput`).

**I want to create a type that holds a chain of these modules, with all intermediate types matching.**

Something like:

```js
type ModuleChain<TInput, TOutput> = ?

const moduleA: Module<string, number> = { ... };
const moduleB: Module<number, Date> = { ... };
const moduleC: Module<Date, string> = { ... };
const moduleD: Module<string, string> = { ... };

const chain1: ModuleChain<string, string> = [moduleA, moduleB, moduleC, moduleD];  // valid
const chain2: ModuleChain<string, Date> = [moduleA, moduleB];  // valid
const badChain: ModuleChain<string, string> = [moduleA, moduleC];  // NOT valid
```

Note: I'm happy for the arrays to be read-only, I know the types don't persist to runtime so I'm thinking more that the arrays of modules will be hard-coded.

I'm aware a better solution is a class holding a `head` and `tail`, and implementing the methods myself, like

```js
class ModuleChain<TInput, TOutput> {
  head: Module<TInput, TIntermediate>;
  tail: ModuleChain<TIntermediate, TOutput>;
}
```

but I can't figure out how to get that to work, as:

1. I can't `infer TIntermediate` outside of a conditional type
2. I can't figure out how to define the base case of a list of length 1 with no `tail`

So, I'd like either a way of typing a flat array with these properties, or the class thing above.

I've had a look at [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) and they don't seem to work for this.

Cursory googles and a discussion with my coworkers are indicating that TypeScript isn't really built for this kind of thing, which may be the case! But I'm curious to see if it's even possible?

Comment: I want to do something like `type ModuleChain<TInput, TOutput> = [Module<TInput, TOutput>] | [Module<TInput, TIntermediate>, ...ModuleChain<TIntermediate, TOutput>];`, but it complains about circular references and also doesn't know what `TIntermediate` is supposed to be

Comment: What are you going to do with a `ModuleChain<I, O>`?  Do you need it to remember the intermediate types?  If so then you'll need to add such types to your definition of `ModuleChain` (so it will end up looking like `ModuleChain<I, T extends any[], O>` where `T` is a tuple of intermediate types).  If not then presumably all you can do is call `passThrough` for all of them at once, you should probably just make a helper function to produce a single `Module<I, O>` from an acceptable chain of modules, and the goal is to write that helper function to reject bad chains.  How should we proceed here?

Comment: [This playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mZZ1om) shows the various options as I see them.  Which, if any, should I expand into an answer?